# Symfony. form_widget auto select for dropdown

Tags: php, twig, symfony

How can I auto select an option in a `form_widget`?

```
{{ form_widget(form.group, {'attr':{'value':varGroup }}) }}
```

The previous snippet only works for text fields, not dropdown. `form.group` is a list of groups, and `varGroup` is the group I need to be selected by default.

Is it possible doing it by using `form_widget` capabilities?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What Field Type did you use for your Form Class? Is it a ChoiceType Field?

Comment: the dropdown is "group" type, it's from a ManyToOne relationship, and it's entity has a__toString() function to return the possible values.

Comment: Maybe you mean `CollectionType`? Can you confirm before you respond to this comment. `group` is not a built-in-field type for Symfony. Can you see [the following link:](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#built-in-field-types)

Comment: Yes It's CollectionType

Comment: You'll also need to post your Form code, just the relevant part where you add the `CollectionType::class` to the form and set the choices. And also, the version of Symfony, you are using either Symfony2 or Symfony3 but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue a few weeks ago, for some reason `varGroup` isn't evaluated within the `form_widget` function call and strange things (read: I can't remember exactly) are set as the value of the `<select>`.

And this doesn't work:

```
{{ form_widget(form.group, {'attr': {'value': {{ varGroup }} } }) }} // Plus it's hideous.
```

The workaround I found was to cast the variable to a string by using the [concat operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators) `~` with an empty string `''`.

```
{{ form_widget(form.group, {'attr': {'value': varGroup ~ '' } }) }}
```